# Path to file with data when deploying app

Tags: java, spring, maven

I want to deploy my web app where I get data from a `json` file. The `path` I am currently using on production is an *absolute* path and it is defined in my `application.properties` like this:

```
objects.filename=C:\\Users\\Hp\\[...]\\Java\\projects\\management\\service\\src\\main\\resources\\files\\objects.json
```

---

```
@Service
public class Service {
    @Value("${objects.filename}")
    private String filename;
    /**code**/
}
```

but for sure it cannot be like this if I want to deploy this app on `aws` server.
On AWS how should the `path` look?
I tried something like this `../files/objects.json` but the app does not work with that path.

I am using maven to build the final `.jar` file

Answer (score 2):

Check which version of java you are using and its path and reset your path and then try to deploy your app.

[image: To set absolute path]

The location of your local repository can be changed in your user configuration. The default value is ${user.home}/.m2/repository/.

Comment: If these are Dockerized containers for AWS then also take a look at how containers store their path.  You can specify how the container mounts, in the event that you really need absolute paths